# postgres search query error if space used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm following along with Ryan Bates' Railscast on full text search with Postgres, however, he's using postgres 9.1 and I'm using 9.2.  He builds the following query to execute a search. It works for me if my query is a single word, such as "superman" but if it's two words, such as `dc comics`, or `super man`, I'm getting this error, which being just new to postgres I can't figure out how to fix. Can you assist?

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error in tsquery: "super man"
LINE 1: ...articles"  WHERE (to_tsvector('english', name) @@ 'super man...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE (to_tsvector('english', name) @@ 'super man' or to_tsvector('english', content) @@ 'super man') ORDER BY       ts_rank(to_tsvector(name), plainto_tsquery('super man')) +
      ts_rank(to_tsvector(content), plainto_tsquery('super man'))
 desc LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
```

query from Article.rb

```
 def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      rank = <<-RANK
      ts_rank(to_tsvector(name), plainto_tsquery(#{sanitize(query)})) +
      ts_rank(to_tsvector(content), plainto_tsquery(#{sanitize(query)}))
    RANK

  where("to_tsvector('english', name) @@ :q or to_tsvector('english', content) @@ :q", q: query).order("#{rank} desc")

    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`@@` is used to compare a `tsvector` with a `tsquery`. You are trying to compare a `tsvector` with something that is not a valid `tsquery`.

`'superman'` is of type `text` and should really be wrapped in a call to `to_tsquery()`. However it looks like postgres has tried to help you out and coerced it into a tsquery for you, and to_tsquery('superman') is a valid query.

`'super man'` is of type `text` and should really be wrapped in a call to `to_tsquery()`. Postgres has **failed** to coerce it into a tsquery for you, since to_tsquery('super man') is **not** a valid query. A valid tsquery must have boolean operators like `&` or `|` to tell the query how to treat the words. 'super & man' would probably work.

To save you having to write queries for simple cases of AND-style queries, `plainto_tsquery` makes this a little easier. In your case wrap your `:q` param in a call to `plainto_tsquery`

```
plainto_tsquery(:q)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wrapped the `:q` twice as you see here, however, even though it doesn't break now on a two word search such as `has been` it doesn't return any results even though `has been` exists in the content of my db. is this what you expect? anyway to make it retrieve results on multi-word search query?  `where("to_tsvector('english', name) @@ plainto_tsquery(:q) or to_tsvector('english', content) @@ plainto_tsquery(:q)", q: query).order("#{rank} desc")`

Comment: Read up on [stop words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html). It's likly that "has" and "been" are deemed too common in the english dictionary to bother indexing them.

Comment: ok, I see. It is returning results for less common words. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't help if you're doing prefix searching though

Comment: I just have question here,

Answer (score 0):

If you want your query to have multiple words, but your Postgres DB to still return results when the query is incomplete, use this:

`SELECT *  FROM <TABLE_NAME> where <TSVECTOR_COLUMN> @@ (phraseto_tsquery('incomplete wo')::text || ':*')::tsquery = true;`